# Why is this cron sometimes activing daily and sometimes every three days? (which it's intended to)

Tags: cron

I have a line in my crontab like this:

```
01 6  * * */3 $TASK
```

The variable $TASK emails me a particular email.  I understand that I have written the cron to trigger this action at 06:01am every third day.

Oddly, this is when I get the emails (screenshot from GMail):

[image]

They are *mostly* every third day, but regularly turn up on consecutive days (today and yesterday; 1st and 2nd March; 23rd and 22nd Feb;...). Can anyone explain what's happening?

EDIT: Ah, is it possible that the Cron server is just resetting entirely on Saturday nights? And if so is that the cron protocol or is that the way the sysadmins have configured things?

```
       2014

      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4                     1                     1
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   2  3  4  5  6  7  8
12 13 14 15 16 17 18   9 10 11 12 13 14 15   9 10 11 12 13 14 15
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  16 17 18 19 20 21 22
26 27 28 29 30 31     23 24 25 26 27 28     23 24 25 26 27 28 29
                                            30 31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said:

```
01 6  * * */3 $TASK
┬  ┬  ┬ ┬  ┬
│  │  │ │  │
│  │  │ │  │
│  │  │ │  └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
│  │  │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
│  │  └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│  └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

As indicated above, your cron job is scheduled for every third day of a **week**.  A week starts on Sunday, so your cron job would execute on Sunday, Wednesday, Saturday.  The beginning of another week causes it to start from Sunday again.

You could fix your cron job by making it execute every third day in a month instead:

```
01 6  */3 * * $TASK
```

You might also want to refer to [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: That would be exactly what I wanted - thank you!